# Remove text between () and [] in python with some exceptions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter some texts with unwanted characters in between texts. Here's a sample text I want to filter.

```
*CHI:\t<that> [/] (.) that (i)s it . [+ bch]\n
```

Attempt:

```
import re
s = '*CHI:\t<that> [/] (.) that (i)s it . [+ bch]\n'
s = re.sub('[()]','',s)
print(s)
```

My output is

```
*CHI:   <that> [/] . that is it . [+ bch]
```

I want to retain (.) but filter parenthesis between i i.e. change (i) to i. While I want to retain [/] and remove [+ bch]. How can I filter one and retain the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class that excludes `.`:

```
s = re.sub(r'\(([^.])\)', r'\1', s)
```

With this change, `s` would become:

```
*CHI:   <that> [/] (.) that is it . [+ bch]
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that will work with both Python versions is

```
re.sub(r'\((?!\.\))|(?<!\(\.)\)', '', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/99MDnu/1)

**Details**

- `\((?!\.\))` - a `(` that is not immediately followed with `.)`
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\(\.)\)` - a `)` not immediately preceded with `(.`.

As an alternative, you may add your exceptions as an alternative inside a capturing group and replace with the backreference (Python 3.5+) or a lambda expression (earlier versions):

```
import re
s = '*CHI:\t<that> [/] (.) that (i)s it . [+ bch]\n'
s = re.sub(r'(\(\.\))|[()]', r'\1', s)
# Python earlier than 3.5
# s = re.sub(r'(\(\.\))|[()]', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', s)
print(s) # => *CHI: <that> [/] (.) that is it . [+ bch]
```

See the [Python 3.5 demo](https://ideone.com/QnzTOc) and [this Python 2.x demo](https://ideone.com/AXcx83).